# Updating custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have custom `ComboBox` control which allows to pick colors, like described in this article [Color Picker using WPF Combobox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140521/Color-Picker-using-WPF-Combobox).

I insert custom `ComboBox` in `MainWindow` this way:

```
            <local:Colorpicker  x:Name="brushesComboBox"></local:Colorpicker>
```

When I select colors manually, it works fine, but if I set the color programmatically like that:

```
brushesComboBox.SelectedColor= new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aquamarine);
```

ComboBox doesn`t update itself.

I understand that I will need to modify the code of Colorpicker class, so that when dependancy property is set it will force to update selected index in the internal combobox. How do I do that?

`Colorpicker` class, xaml part:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfParabola.Colorpicker"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfParabola"
            xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" Name="uccolorpicker"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            d:DesignHeight="20" d:DesignWidth="200">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetType"
                ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Type}" x:Key="colorsTypeOdp">
                <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                    <sys:String>System.Windows.Media.Colors, PresentationCore,
                                Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
                                PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35</sys:String>
                </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            </ObjectDataProvider>
            <ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource colorsTypeOdp}"
                MethodName="GetProperties" x:Key="colorPropertiesOdp">
            </ObjectDataProvider>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Name="superCombo"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource colorPropertiesOdp}}"
            SelectedValuePath="Name"
            SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=uccolorpicker,
            Path=SelectedColor}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Width="50" Height="{Binding ElementName=FontSize+4}" Margin="2" Background="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock  TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

`Colorpicker` class, code behind:

```
    public partial class Colorpicker : UserControl
    {
    public Colorpicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        superCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    public Brush SelectedColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(SelectedColorProperty); }
        set{SetValue(SelectedColorProperty, value);}
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(Colorpicker), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add callback to your dependency property and find the index based on the new Brush value. You can modify your SelectedColorProperty initialization below.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(Colorpicker), new PropertyMetadata(default(Brush), OnSelectedColorChanged));

private static void OnSelectedColorChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var newBrush = (Brush)e.NewValue;
    var colorPicker = (Colorpicker)d;
    var comboBox = colorPicker.superCombo;

    // Find your index here using the new Brush value.
    // And update the selected index of your ComboBox.
}
```